# Creación de .txt con Scanner en Java

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Buenos días, ante todo presentarme  ya que es mi primer post, me llamo Raúl y estoy aprendiendo Java actualmente.
Estoy practicando con un código que hará lo siguiente :
-El programa buscará el archivo prueba2.txt en la ruta seleccionada.
-En caso de no existir el programa , dará la ópcion al usuario de crear un nuevo archivo.
 /* Aquí me viene la duda, quiero que el usuario inserte por teclado el nombre del nuevo archivo :
(/*File archivo = new File("C:\Users\Raul\Desktop\"+nuevoFichero);/*¿Cómo crear el fichero nuevo con nombre introducido por teclado?*/

-En caso de que el archivo prueba2.txt exista el usuario podrá leer y modificar 
el archivo con los siguientes bloques de código.

A parte de dicha duda agradeceré cualqiuer tipo de recomendación sobre buenas prácticas y mejores en el código ya que aún estoy empezando, un saludo.

El código es el siguiente:

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;//Importamos todas las clases de java.io.

public class lecturaArchivo {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    File dir = new File("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\prueba2.txt");

    if (!dir.exists()){

        System.out.println("El archivo no existe");

        System.out.println("¿Desea crear un nuevo fichero de texto? Pulse Y para crear el archivo, cualquier otra tecla para finalizar el programa");

        String Ynuevo = sc.nextLine();

        if (Ynuevo.equals("Y")){
            System.out.println("Nombre del nuevo fichero : ");
            String nuevoFichero = sc.nextLine();
            File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\"+nuevoFichero);/*¿Cómo crear el fichero nuevo con nombre introducido por teclado?*/

            archivo.getAbsoluteFile();

            System.out.println("El archivo se ha creado correctamente");

        }else{
            System.out.println("El programa se cerrará");
        }
    }else{
    try

       (BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\prueba2.txt"));
        BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\prueba2.txt"));){
        //Escribimos en el fichero

    System.out.println("Introduzca el exto a introducir en el fichero");
    String escritura = sc.nextLine();
        bw.write(escritura);
        bw.newLine();
        bw.write("Seguimos usando Buffered");
        //Guardamos los cambios del fichero
        bw.flush();
        //Leemos el fichero y lo mostramos por pantalla
        String linea=br.readLine();
        while(linea!=null){
            System.out.println(linea);
            linea=br.readLine();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println("Error E/S: "+e);
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para crear el archivo tienes que utilizar el metodo `createNewFile()` del objeto tipo File.

```
if (Ynuevo.equals("Y")){
        System.out.println("Nombre del nuevo fichero : ");
        String nuevoFichero = sc.nextLine();
        File archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\Raul\\Desktop\\"+nuevoFichero);/*¿Cómo crear el fichero nuevo con nombre introducido por teclado?*/

        archivo.createNewFile(); // Esta sentencia es la que crea el archivo.
        archivo.getAbsoluteFile();

        System.out.println("El archivo se ha creado correctamente");

    }else{
        System.out.println("El programa se cerrará");
    }
```

Comment: solucionado, gracias!